# creating directories, but not doing it how i want it to do

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have created a powershell script that will create directories:

```
function Create-C:Directory{
md C:\DATA
}

function Create-C:DirectoryLOG{
md C:\Log
}

$TestCDrive = Test-Path C:\DATA
IF ($TestCDrive  = "False")
        {Create-C:Directory}
ELSE
        {Write-Host "C Data Directory Exists"}

$TestCDriveLOG = Test-Path C:\Log
IF ($TestCDriveLOG = "False")
        {Create-C:DirectoryLOG}
ELSE
        {Write-Host "C LOG Directory Exists"}
```

I believe i have told the code that if the test-path is false then create else write-host. I believe this code to do as i expected?

Results:
When i run this 1st time it will create me the directories.
But for testing purposes when i run it again i expected it to tell me that the directory exists already but instead it gives me a red error message saying:

```
md: An item with the soecified name C:\DATA already exists.
```

And the same for C:\Log. I really dont understand how to deal with this, i ve spent alot of time on it to figure out but no luck. Hope someone can help

Comment: `=` is assignment. `-eq` is test.

Comment: ya i tried -eq instead of the '=' its still same output unfortunately. this is the full error code:    md : An item with the specified name C:\DATA already exists.
At line:2 char:5
+     md C:\DATA
+     ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (C:\DATA:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryExist,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

Comment: `if (Test-Path C:\DATA) {Create-C:Directory} else {Write-Host "C Data Directory Exists"}`?

Comment: This use of temporary variables and one-off functions is really odd to begin with as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: so just to confirm. that code means that if the test-path is True then execute the function? i tried it, it prints the statement instead

Comment: basically, if the path is false i want to execute function, or if it returns true i.e. the path is existing then it should print the statement

Comment: lol i just played around with what you suggested. one of the codes made sense and works perfectly fine mate.         if (Test-Path C:\DATA) {Write-Host "C Data Directory Exists"} else {Create-C:Directory}

Comment: `Test-Path` returns `$true` when its argument exists. If that isn't working for you then something is very wrong. And yes, your logic was inverted and I didn't correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, your logic was just a little off:

```
function Create-C:DirectoryLOG{
md C:\Log
}

IF (!(Test-Path C:\DATA))
        {Create-C:Directory}
ELSE
        {Write-Host "C Data Directory Exists"}

IF (!(Test-Path C:\log))
        {Create-C:DirectoryLOG}
ELSE
        {Write-Host "C LOG Directory Exists"}
```

Comment: jsut one question mate. that exclamation mark u have in the IF statement, what does that do?

Comment: The exclamation is the same as "not".